# Expandable summary view for a large expression

Tags: front-end, output-formatting, expression-manipulation, visualization, elided-forms

I need a convenient interface to interactively explore very large expressions. I am aware of `Short` and `Shallow`, and appreciate the front-end feature that allows to show a large expression in initially concise and gradually expandable form, with placeholders for collapsed expressions. I would like something similar to this, but with some additional features. In particular, I would like to be able to both expand and collapse sub-expressions, view a summary of a collapsed sub-expression in its tooltip (`Head`, `Length`, `Depth`, `LeafCount` — ideally, customizable), and have a way to copy a sub-expression to the clipboard. Is there anything similar to this?

Comment: One particular scenario where I could use it is large expression simplification. Sometimes `FullSimplify` cannot make much progress in a reasonable time, but I found that if I manually identify sub-expressions that seems "simplifiable" and apply `FullSimplify` specifically to them, then I can often achieve significant simplification much faster.

Comment: maybe something like `expr1= RandomInteger[5,{2,2}];
expr2=Partition[{a,b,c,d},2];
labels= {"expr 1","expr 2"};
fview =FlipView[{ Tooltip[Iconize[#,#2],Grid@#],#}]&;
MapThread[fview,{{expr1,expr2}, labels}]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code does what I think you want:

1. Right clicking converts the selected portion into a button with a ».
2. Clicking on the » expands the button back into the selected portion.
3. The "HotKeys" option allows you to define rules so that a hot key will apply a desired function on the selected portion.
4. The tooltip that is created can be customized by modifying the `$ExpandableInformation` global variable.

Here is an animation of the code in action:

[image]

You will see expressions collapsed when right-clicking, and simplified when using the "F" key.

One issue is that quitting the kernel will disable the form.

Here is the code:

```
Options[ExpandableForm] = {"HotKeys" -> {}};

ExpandableForm /: MakeBoxes[ExpandableForm[expr_, OptionsPattern[]], StandardForm] := With[
    {
    events = 
        {
        {"MouseClicked", 2} :> NotebookApply[
            SelectedNotebook[],
            collapsedBoxes[NotebookRead[SelectedNotebook[]]],
            All
        ], (* right clicking collapses the selected expression *)
        Sequence @@ addEvents[OptionValue[ExpandableForm, "HotKeys"]]
        (* process "HotKeys" options *)
        }
    },
    With[{boxes = MakeBoxes[expr, StandardForm]},
        TemplateBox[
            {
            (* setup EventHandler *)
            TagBox[boxes, EventHandlerTag[events]],
            boxes
            },
            "FOO",
            DisplayFunction -> (#1&),
            InterpretationFunction -> (#2&)
        ]
    ]
]

(* make ExpandableForm a wrapper *)
Unprotect[$OutputForms];
 $OutputForms = DeleteDuplicates @ Append[$OutputForms, ExpandableForm];
 Protect[$OutputForms];

(* code to process and implement hot keys *)

addEvents[key_Rule] := addEvents[{key}]
addEvents[keys:{___Rule}] := Replace[
    keys,
    Rule[key_, f_] :> key :> applyFunctionToSelection[f],
    {1}
]

applyFunctionToSelection[f_] := Module[{expr},
    expr = ToExpression[NotebookRead[SelectedNotebook[]], StandardForm, Hold];
    If[MatchQ[expr, _Hold],
        NotebookWrite[
            SelectedNotebook[], 
        Replace[expr, Hold[a_] :> ToBoxes@f[a]]
        ]
    ]
]

(* code to collapse boxes *)
collapsedBoxes[boxes_] := TemplateBox[
    {"»", boxes},
    "Collapse",
    DisplayFunction -> (ButtonBox[
        #,
        ButtonFunction :> NotebookWrite[ParentBox @ EvaluationBox[], #2, All],
        Evaluator -> Automatic
    ]&),
    InterpretationFunction -> (#2&),
    Tooltip -> ToBoxes @ boxInfo[boxes]
]

(* gather expression information *)
boxInfo[boxes_] := Quiet[
    Check[
        ToExpression[boxes, StandardForm, expressionInfo],
        {}
    ],
    ToExpression::esntx
]

SetAttributes[expressionInfo, HoldAll];

expressionInfo[expr_] := Grid[
    Replace[
        $ExpandableInformation,
        (label_ -> h_) :> {Row[{label,":"}], h[Unevaluated @ expr]},
        {1}
    ],
    Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Baseline}
]

(* customizable global variable to control what the tooltip shows *)

$ExpandableInformation = {
    "Head" -> Head,
    "Length" -> Length,
    "Depth" -> Depth,
    "LeafCount" -> LeafCount
};
```